# user bug in my app I can not reproduce

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gps, android-location

I have a feature in my app that gets a users gps coordinates then returns nearby breweries. When I use the feature it has never forced closed, and others have tested it to and it worked. One user reported this error when they opened the activity that gets the user location and tries to get the location of breweries:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro/com.example.beerportfoliopro.FindBrewery}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.beerportfoliopro.FindBrewery.onCreate(FindBrewery.java:42)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
... 11 more
```

My activity that is launched is:

```
package com.example.beerportfoliopro;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro.R;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by mike on 7/3/13.
 */
public class FindBrewery extends ActionbarMenu {


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




        setContentView(R.layout.beer_location_list);

        String title = "Nearby Breweries";
        TextView topTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.beerLocationTitle);
        topTitle.setText(title);

        //get user location

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();



        //construct url
        String url = myURLandKey;

        Log.d("urlTest",url);

        //async task goes here
        new GetNearbyBreweries(this).execute(url);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Lastly my asynctask is:

```
package com.example.beerportfoliopro;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro.R;

public class GetNearbyBreweries extends AsyncTask
        <String, Void, String> {

    Context c;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;

    public GetNearbyBreweries (Context context)
    {
        c = context;
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Locating Breweries");

        Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //decode json here
        try{
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);


            //acces listview
            ListView lv = (ListView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.locationList);

            //make array list for beer
            final List<BreweryLocationData> tasteList = new ArrayList<BreweryLocationData>();



            for(int i = 0; i < json.getJSONArray("data").length(); i++) {

                String brewery = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("brewery").getString("name");
                String id = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("brewery").getString("id");
                String latitude = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getString("latitude");
                String longitude = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getString("longitude");
                String distance = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(i).getString("distance");



                int count = i + 1;


                //create object
                BreweryLocationData tempLocation = new BreweryLocationData(brewery, id, longitude , latitude,distance);

                //add to arraylist
                tasteList.add(tempLocation);


                //add items to listview
                BreweryLocationInfoAdapter adapter1 = new BreweryLocationInfoAdapter(c ,R.layout.listview_item_row, tasteList);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter1);

                //set up clicks
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        BreweryLocationData o=(BreweryLocationData)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                        String tempID = o.id;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c, tempID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();

                        //get beer details from id

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(c, BreweryPage2.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("id", tempID);
                        c.startActivity(myIntent);


                    }
                });




            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.beerportfoliopro.FindBrewery.onCreate(FindBrewery.java:42)` What is line 42?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a force close when attempting to get the users location.  I would add validation that the use has GPS enabled and if not then give them an alert dialog asking them to enable, you may also send them directly to GPS settings.

Comment: how can I check if gps is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Can the user reproduce the error?

From your code listing it seems line 42 is(maybe you edited it though):

```
39 LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
40 Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
41 double longitude = location.getLongitude();
42 double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

Cant see why getLatitude() would break and not getLongitude()

You should validate location, to make sure you have it.

Comment: I am not sure if the user can reproduce it. The error reports in the developers console do not show who reported the error.

Answer (score 0):

As a couple of others have pointed out, it is telling you that the error is on line 42. Unfortunately you have slightly affected the line numbers pasting it here. On your line 42 you are assuming something is not null, and it actually is null.

Given that LocationManager#getLastKnownLocation can return null, and you're not checking for that, I'd say that was your issue, and that your line 42 is where you call location.getLongitude().

getLastKnownLocation will only return a Location if the provider you specify has been used recently. If nothing has forced it to find a location yet, or for a long time (Android considers the last location too old to be correct), then you will get null.